# Problems using an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to pass the value of an editText from a class to another. In the first class, I use this code to obtain the value of the editText:

```
number = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText10);
text=number.getText().toString();//obtain the value
```

where "text" is a static string. Later I use this code that returns the `STATIC` string "text":

```
public static String rete()   
{
    return text;
}
```

And finally, I get the value in the second class using this:

```
String text2 = Pruebita2.rete();
```

where `Pruebita2` is the name of the first class.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to transfer data between classes is to pass the string "text" via an intent to the second class.

Eg.

Activity1:  Create the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
           intent.putExtra("text_key", text); 
           context.startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2: Get the vlaue

```
text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text_key");
```